# Android - ListRowPresenter with fixed position for selected items

Tags: android, gridview, browsefragment, listrowpresenter

I have ListRow in an android project and everything looks fine. The current behavior is, I can browse elements in my Row, the selected item keeps centered, but when I get to the end, the selected item goes to the end (right aligned). Also when selecting the first element, it is selected on the leftmost part of the screen.

What I'd like to achieve is that the selected item in my list is always centered, or even in any other position, but it has to be the same position always.

I am not the android expert and I am not sure if there is already a class or widget that can do this, or this can be achieved with programming tricks.

Sorry for my poor English. Any clue? I am attaching an image explaining it much better. "S" means the selected item.

[Picture of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQaRI.png)

[Second picture showing actual results vs needed results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxVX1.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you currently have?

Comment: It is a BrowseFragment with ListRowPresenter as an adapter. Everything is working fine, but I want to change behavior when an element is selected. I want them all to, when selected, are located in the same horizontal position. I will add an image to show more details.

Do you mean paste the code or what do you mean with "what do I currently have"? Thank you!